# Checkbox not updating SQL query on button press using PHP

Tags: php, html

With this code, it can retrieve the values from the database with a checkbox on each row. What I want for it to do is to update the unchecked values (namely 0) in the database with 1 for each checkbox checked.

Here's the query for the database and some sample rows.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `job_order` (
`ID` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`SI_no` varchar(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`Date_Issued` date NOT NULL,
`Date_completed` date DEFAULT NULL,
`checked` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `job_order` (`ID`, `SI_no`, `Date_Issued`, `Date_completed`, 
`checked`) VALUES
(1, '2', '2018-12-19', '2018-12-26', 1),
(2, '5', '2018-11-06', '2018-12-04', 1),
(3, '7', '2018-12-01', '2018-12-13', 0),
(4, '8', '2018-12-20', '2018-12-12', 0);
 COMMIT;
```

db_c.php - the class file

```
<?php

define ( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );
define ( 'DB_USER', 'root' );
define ( 'DB_PASS', '' );
define ( 'DB_NAME', 'db_name' );


class db_c{  
    public $mysqli;
    function __construct() {
          $this->mysqli = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
          if(!$this->mysqli){
            die('Could not Connect My Sql:' .mysql_error());
          }
    }
    function complete_orders($orders){
        $processed = array();
        if(is_array($orders) && !empty($orders)){
            if(isset($order['order-complete'])){
                foreach($order['order-complete'] as $ids){
                    $sql = "UPDATE `job_order` SET `checked`= 1 WHERE `ID` = ?";
                    if($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($sql)){
                        $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
                            if($stmt->execute()){
                               array_push($processed, $id);  
                            }
                    }
                }
                return $processed;
            }else{
                 echo '<script>console.log("Nothing returned line 32")</script>';
                return 0; //No orders selected
            }
        }else{
              echo '<script>console.log("Nothing processed")</script>';
            return 0; //Nothing to process
        }
    }
    function return_orders(){
        $orders = array();
        $sql = "SELECT `ID`, `SI_no`, `date_issued`, `date_completed`, `checked` FROM `job_order` WHERE `checked` != 1";
        if($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($sql)){
                if($stmt->execute()){
                    $stmt->bind_result($ID, $SI_no, $date_issued, $date_completed, $checked);
                    $stmt->store_result();
                    while($stmt->fetch()){
                           $orders[$ID]['SI_no'] = $SI_no;
                           $orders[$ID]['Issued'] = $date_issued;
                           $orders[$ID]['Completed'] = $date_completed;
                           $orders[$ID]['Checked'] = $checked;
                    }
                    return $orders;
                }else{
                    return 1;
                // failed to execute
                }
        }else{
            return 0;
            // failed to prepare
        }
    }
    function orders_2_table(){
        $unchecked = $this->return_orders();
        if(is_array($unchecked) && !empty($unchecked)){
            //returned results, build rows
            $table = '';
            foreach($unchecked as $id => $dets){
              $table .= '<tr><td>'.$dets['SI_no'].'</td><td>'.$dets['Issued'].'</td><td>'.$dets['Completed'].'</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="order-complete[]" value="'.$id.'"  /></td></tr>';  
            }
            return array('Rows'=>$table, 'Count'=>count($unchecked));
        }elseif(!is_array($unchecked)){
            if($unchecked === 0){
                return array('Rows'=>'<tr><td colspan="3">Error (SQL) </td></tr>', 'Count'=>0);
            }else{
                return array('Rows'=>'<tr><td colspan="3">Error (EXE) </td></tr>', 'Count'=>0);
            }
        }else{
            return array('Rows'=>'<tr><td colspan="3">All Orders Completed </td></tr>', 'Count'=>0);
        }
    }

}
?>
```

I'm mostly having problems with the function complete_orders, which doesn't return anything on button press of the submit button. Nor does it check if the checkboxes are ticked.

Here's the HTML layout file

jobrequestfilter.php

```
<?php 

session_start();
include 'db_c.php';

$dbc = new db_c();
$msg = '';
if(isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['process_orders'])){
    $process = $dbc->complete_orders($_POST);
    if(is_array($process) && !empty($process)){
        $msg = '<tr><td colspan="3">Successfully Processed '.count($process).' Orders</td></tr>';
    }
    else{
        echo '<script>console.log("Nothing processed at jobrequestfilter")</script>';
     }
}

$data = $dbc->orders_2_table();

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Job Request Chart</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="navbar">
            <div id ="wrap">
                <div class="logo"></div> 
                <img id="b" class="b">
            </div>
        </div>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <div id="filterby">
               <input type="submit" id="Email" class="requestbutton" name="Email" value="Email">
            </div>
        </form>
        <form method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <table id ="jobtable">
                <tr><th>SI no.</th><th>Date Issued</th><th>Date Started </th><th>Approve?</th></tr>
                <?php echo $msg ?> 
                <?php echo $data['Rows'] ?>
                <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="process_orders" value="Process Orders" /></td><td>Count:<?php echo $data['Count'] ?></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The isset button returns the echo statement I put, however, most seems to be working fine except for the process order button. Is it wise to just use javascript for the checkbox on update?

Comment: change `$id` to `$ids` in `$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);` and `array_push($processed, $id);` as your loop is `foreach($order['order-complete'] as $ids)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

db_c.php

1. It should not be

> $order['order-complete']

But

> $orders

Because the array variable name from post already stored in variable $orders.

2. It should not be

> $id

But

> $ids

Because you declare it as

> foreach($orders as $ids)

```
<?php

define ( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );
define ( 'DB_USER', 'root' );
define ( 'DB_PASS', '' );
define ( 'DB_NAME', 'your_db_name' );


class db_c{  
    public $mysqli;
    function __construct() {
          $this->mysqli = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
          if(!$this->mysqli){
            die('Could not Connect My Sql:' .mysql_error());
          }
    }
    function complete_orders($orders){
        $processed = array();
        if(is_array($orders) && !empty($orders)){
            if(isset($orders)){
                foreach($orders as $ids){
                    $sql = "UPDATE `job_order` SET `checked`= 1 WHERE `id` = ?";
                    if($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($sql)){
                        $stmt->bind_param("i", $ids);
                            if($stmt->execute()){
                               array_push($processed, $ids);  
                            }
                    }
                }
                return $processed;
            }else{
                 echo '<script>console.log("Nothing returned line 32")</script>';
                return 0; //No orders selected
            }
        }else{
              echo '<script>console.log("Nothing processed")</script>';
            return 0; //Nothing to process
        }
    }
    function return_orders(){
        $orders = array();
        $sql = "SELECT `ID`, `SI_no`, `date_issued`, `date_completed`, `checked` FROM `job_order` WHERE `checked` != 1";
        if($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($sql)){
                if($stmt->execute()){
                    $stmt->bind_result($ID, $SI_no, $date_issued, $date_completed, $checked);
                    $stmt->store_result();
                    while($stmt->fetch()){
                           $orders[$ID]['SI_no'] = $SI_no;
                           $orders[$ID]['Issued'] = $date_issued;
                           $orders[$ID]['Completed'] = $date_completed;
                           $orders[$ID]['Checked'] = $checked;
                    }
                    return $orders;
                }else{
                    return 1;
                // failed to execute
                }
        }else{
            return 0;
            // failed to prepare
        }
    }
    function orders_2_table(){
        $unchecked = $this->return_orders();
        if(is_array($unchecked) && !empty($unchecked)){
            //returned results, build rows
            $table = '';
            foreach($unchecked as $id => $dets){
              $table .= '<tr><td>'.$dets['SI_no'].'</td><td>'.$dets['Issued'].'</td><td>'.$dets['Completed'].'</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="order-complete[]" value="'.$id.'"  /></td></tr>';  
            }
            return array('Rows'=>$table, 'Count'=>count($unchecked));
        }elseif(!is_array($unchecked)){
            if($unchecked === 0){
                return array('Rows'=>'<tr><td colspan="3">Error (SQL) </td></tr>', 'Count'=>0);
            }else{
                return array('Rows'=>'<tr><td colspan="3">Error (EXE) </td></tr>', 'Count'=>0);
            }
        }else{
            return array('Rows'=>'<tr><td colspan="3">All Orders Completed </td></tr>', 'Count'=>0);
        }
    }

}
?>
```

jobrequestfilter.php

3.It should not

> if(isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['process_orders'])){
>       $process = $dbc->complete_orders($_POST);

It should be

> if(isset($_POST['order-complete']) &&
>   isset($_POST['process_orders'])){
>       $process = $dbc->complete_orders($_POST['order-complete']);

```
<?php 

session_start();
include 'db_c.php';

$dbc = new db_c();
$msg = '';
if(isset($_POST['order-complete']) && isset($_POST['process_orders'])){
    $process = $dbc->complete_orders($_POST['order-complete']);
    if(is_array($process) && !empty($process)){
        $msg = '<tr><td colspan="3">Successfully Processed '.count($process).' Orders</td></tr>';
    }
    else{
        echo '<script>console.log("Nothing processed at jobrequestfilter")</script>';
     }
}

$data = $dbc->orders_2_table();

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Job Request Chart</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="navbar">
            <div id ="wrap">
                <div class="logo"></div> 
                <img id="b" class="b">
            </div>
        </div>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <div id="filterby">
               <input type="submit" id="Email" class="requestbutton" name="Email" value="Email">
            </div>
        </form>
        <form method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <table id ="jobtable">
                <tr><th>SI no.</th><th>Date Issued</th><th>Date Started </th><th>Approve?</th></tr>
                <?php echo $msg ?> 
                <?php echo $data['Rows'] ?>
                <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="process_orders" value="Process Orders" /></td><td>Count:<?php echo $data['Count'] ?></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace below complete_orders function code

```
function complete_orders($orders){
        $processed = array();
        if(is_array($orders) && !empty($orders)){
            if(isset($orders['order-complete'])){       
                foreach($orders['order-complete'] as $id){
                    $sql = "UPDATE `job_order` SET `checked`= 1 WHERE `ID` = ?";
                    if($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($sql)){
                        $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
                            if($stmt->execute()){
                               array_push($processed, $id);  
                            }
                    }
                }       
                return $processed;
            }else{
                 echo '<script>console.log("Nothing returned line 32")</script>';
                return 0; //No orders selected
            }
        }else{
              echo '<script>console.log("Nothing processed")</script>';
            return 0; //Nothing to process
        }
    }
```

Two problem in code:

1. Function argument $orders you are passing but while process you using order. So it's was not going inside into loop
2. in foreach iteration your are using ids but while updating query you using id. so change variable accordingly. Please check